# ¿Cómo puedo crear etiquetas a partir de los valores de atributos usando XSLT?

Tags: xml, atributos, xsl, xslt, elementos

Tengo un archivo XML con información exportada de una base de datos.
Simplificando sería algo así:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="transformabd.xsl"?>
    <database name="basedatosejemplo">
        <table name="categorias">
            <column name="codCategoria">alfileres</column>
            <column name="descripcion">NULL</column>
            <column name="imagen">NULL</column>
        </table>
        <table name="categorias">
            <column name="codCategoria">anillos</column>
            <column name="descripcion">NULL</column>
            <column name="imagen">NULL</column>
        </table>
           <table name="clientes">
            <column name="codCliente">001</column>
            <column name="empresa">Taller Gráfico</column>
            <column name="nombre">Carmen</column>
            <column name="apellido1">Pérez</column>
            <column name="apellido2">Soler</column>
           </table>
    </database>
```

Me gustaría transformar el documento original de forma que los valores de los atributos "name" pasen a ser los nombres de las etiquetas y que resultara algo así:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="transformabd.xsl"?>
    <basedatosejemplo>
     <categorias>
            <codCategoria>alfileres</codCategoria>
            <descripcion>NULL</descripcion>descripicion>
            <imagen>NULL</imagen>
    </categorias>
    <categorias>
            <codCategoria>anillos</codCategoria>
            <descripcion>NULL</descripcion>descripicion>
            <imagen>NULL</imagen>
    </categorias>        
    <clientes>
            <codCliente>001</codCliente>
            <empresa">Taller Gráfico</empresa>
            <nombre">Carmen</nombre>
            <apellido1>Pérez</apellido1>
            <apellido2>Soler</apellido2>
           </clientes>
    </database>
```

No tengo experiencia en transformación pero me daba la impresión de que no debía ser algo difícil pero la verdad es que me está volviendo un poco loca y he llegado a la conclusión de que no entiendo muy bien los mecanismos de transformación.
¿Se puede hacer lo que quiero?
¿Alguna sugerencia de cómo hacerlo?
Muchísimas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Al final he conseguido lo que quería usando XQuery en lugar de XSLT.
Dejo aquí el código por si a alguien le resultara útil.

```
for $columna in /database/table/column
let $nuevonombre:=$columna/@name
return rename node $columna as $nuevonombre,

for $tabla in /database/table
let $nuevonombre:=$tabla/@name
return rename node $tabla as $nuevonombre,

for $atributo in //@*
return (delete node $atributo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Con XSLT sería:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="*[@name]">
    <xsl:element name="{@name}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Como la otra respuesta utilizando XQuery, va a fallar si hay un valor en el atributo `@name` que no funciona como nombre de un elemento en XML.